# Can i port object files compiled for intel 486 to newer architecture?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a plain c object file file.o compiled for intel 486 and vxworks 5.0 RTOS using gcc cygnus 2.7 in tornado 2.0 environment. I have a couple of questions:

Q1: can this file be linked in an executable to target and run on other CPU architecture like ARM?

Q2: can this file be linked in an executable to target and run on higher models of intel CPU?

Q3: can this file be linked to an executable for target os like micrium or free rtos or higher versions of vxworks?

A detailed solution and suggested portability options are highly appreciated.

Comment: One of the techniques "recompiling" to whatever different architecture is like... disassembling binaries and translating directly to C. Simple variable for registry, loop of `movs`, etc. In practice optimizer deals with it well. Even thought, code itself is not that easily editable or readable.

Comment: As far as i understand, there is no authentic way to decompile an object file into plain c code. I have some object files .o provided by some third party for a certain architecture as specified above. I have written my own plain c code and also included those .o files in my application. Now i want to upgrade my platform to newer cpu architecture and os.

Comment: @Ulmer Malik, the point was... not decompiling. But disassembling and translating it to C code. As I mentioned, You can easily translate instructions like... `movs` to `memcpy()`, or... registry access to C variables. And leaving C compiler to do the rest.  An example would be [Starcraft for ARM](http://hackaday.com/2014/07/31/playing-starcraft-on-an-arm/) port. This isn't that easy. But it's doable.

Comment: You mean translating the binary code to c code? I read from some other post that plain c compiled object files are relatively simpler and less complex ABI. Do we have some tool for that?

Comment: I mean using disassembler to get assembly listing from binary first. Sadly, You might need some customized toolkit for the next step (translating assembly to C). I could find only a few more or less ready solutions, for example for Pandora. And mentioned Starcraft port.

Comment: Regarding Q2: Possible, if the object file format is still supported and the file doesn't use any non standard/non available runtime. You can test this by trying compiling a demo. About Q1: Porting to different architecture require either the C source or a tool that can understand the object file format, translate the instructions from x86 to ARM and repack the object file or that do as Kamiccolo says. I don't know about Q3, maybe checking those OSes ABI would help.

Comment: If you have the original source code, you could work on porting THAT to target platform. Otherwise, you are likely STUCK. Even if you could get past the link phase, there is no practical way to verify every code path works as expected.

Comment: Sounds like static version of QEMU?

Comment: Can you recommend any tools which can disassemble my file.o into assembly language. I have used gcc Cygnus 2.7 using windriver tornado 2.0 to compile my plain c files.